# Django REST AngularJS NGINX Config

Tags: django, angularjs, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I have set up a server according to this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04

Everything is working a-okay, but I would like to change my NGINX set up to incorporate AngularJS for the front end.  Right now I have it configured as the tutorial says and when I visit myip/ I get my  Django app, and when I go to myip/static/ I get my static files.  Great.

What I would like to do is serve the Django API from a api.myip subdomain, and have myip/ actually point to my static (angular app) files.

Any insight on how to configure NGINX to route this correctly?

NGINX Config currently looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location / {
        root /home/user/myproject;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.server_domain_or_IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```